# Cannot create a new dimension

Tags: visual-studio-2019, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, analysis, wizard

I have problems with creating a new dimension in Visual Studio. I want to use an existing table. After setting main table, I can't click next. Also, name columns option is blocked. What should I do to succesfully create a new dimension?

[image]

Comment: Are you using SSAS ?

Comment: Are you using an existing table? or generating a time table in the data source/server?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. As I recall, I clicked on main table or data source view once again, and then next option was enabled.